# php preg_match regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Still having RegEx issues.. Need to match the following characters

a-zA-z9-0 , . ' " ( ) _ - : (SPACE)

Not all the values will have all these but could have them. I have everything withing but the parentheses, Single and Double Quoytes

```
/^[\w. ,\/:_-]+$/
```

UPDATE:

I got it working with this: `"/^[\w. ,:()'\"-]+$/"`

```
$val_1 = "Abh acb 123 . - _ 's ";
$val_2 = "Asc";
$val_3 = "234";
$val_4 = "nj%"; // Fail
$val_5 = "Help (me)";
$val_6 = "What's wrong?"; // Fail
$val_7 = "She's here";
$val_8 = "No: 123.00, 432.00";
$val_9 = 'Need to " Double" ';

$var_array = array($val_1, $val_2, $val_3, $val_4, $val_5, $val_6, $val_7, $val_8, $val_9);

foreach ($var_array as $k=>$d) {
    if ((preg_match("/^[\w. ,:()'\"-]+$/", $d))) {
        echo "Yeah it matches!!!<span style='color:green'>".$d."</span><br />";
    } else {
        echo "Try again, thie FAILED<span style='color:red'>".$d."</span><br />";
    }
}
```

Thanks for all for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the other submitting I have found the solution that works:

```
"/^[\w. ,:()'\"-]+$/"
```

Thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
$pat = "/^[\w. ,\\/:_()'\"-]/";
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all those, you just need:

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9,.'\"()_- :]/", $string);
```

Comment: Should escape the - :) It will give error this way, or not work correctly (possibly this one)

Comment: I have a match almost exactly like this and I don't escape hyphens, works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[-a-zA-Z0-9,.'"()_: ]+$/
```

This should work. But if you put it into a string be sure to escape the needed quotes.